# alternatives to "bucket list of kate"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I want to say: "kate's bucket list" but we need to have "kate" at the end of the sentence (that is the requirement). So I thought of "bucket list of kate" but it sounded a bit.... I don't know... bad in my ear.

Is "bucket list of kate" correct, or is there another better alternative to keep kate at the end of the phrase?

Thanks

Comment: It's technically correct, but you are right in perceiving that it doesn't "sound right".  You could say, eg, "the bucket list belonging to Kate".

Comment: Give us a reason why "Kate" needs to be at the end. Give us context. Is it because it needs to rhyme? More context defenitely doesn't complicate the matter.

Comment: Since Kate purportedly created it, why not a *bucket list by kate*? If someone is imposing this do-before-die obligation, perhaps a *bucket list for kate*?

Comment: Might it be a good idea to start by at least giving Kate the courtesy of a capital K?

Comment: @bib thank you, I think I will go with your suggestion to use "by". add it in the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Kate purportedly created it, why not *a bucket list by Kate*? If someone is imposing this do-before-die obligation, perhaps *a bucket list for Kate*?

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
bucket list of Kate's
```

I think it's not strictly grammatical, but it's the common way to invert phrases like this. It prevents an ambiguity, where the phrase could be misunderstood to mean *bucket list containing Kate*.

Comment: It's totally grammatical. Illogical, frustrating, and not an invariable rule (an enemy of England; the wife of that man who bought the wonderful old china vase the other day) – but grammatical.